# Page being loaded twice

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a ASP.NET 4.0 application with the Patterns and Practices MVP pattern.  When I was debugging today I noticed that my page load was being fired twice.  When I turned on Fiddler (A HTTP Traffic Monitoring Tool) I was able to pinpoint that my Page was actually being downloaded twice.  I'm wondering if anyone has any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any image tags with "#" for source `<img src="#"/>`

Comment: I'm sorry, my initial answer was wrong. This new answer will cause it though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, img tags with no "src" attribute or pointing to a non-existing file can strangly trigger the Page Load event.